# finding parameters numerically

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods

I suspect that a function $f(x,y)$ is of the form $f(x,y)=a(bx+c)^{dy+e}$. If I have access to several values of $f(x,y)$, how do I proceed numerically to find the parameters $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$?

By plotting $\log f$ versus $\log y$ for a fixed $x$, I would get a linear curve and this would give me hope to find $\{d,e\}$. But getting $\{b,c\}$ is beyond me right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's any amount of noise in your data, you probably want to get a bunch of evaluations $\hat{f}(x_i,y_i)$ and then fit $f_{a,b,c,d,e}$ to these data points, for example by minimizing the squared $\ell_2$ error:

$$
C(a,b,c,d,e) := \sum_i \left(\hat{f}(x_i,y_i) - f_{a,b,c,d,e}(x_i,y_i)\right)^2
$$

or the squared log $\ell_2$ error:

$$
C(a,b,c,d,e) := \sum_i \left(\log \hat{f}(x_i,y_i) - \log f_{a,b,c,d,e}(x_i,y_i)\right)^2.
$$

To solve these optimization problems there are many techniques, most of which have good implementations in most scientific programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

You can try putting $x=2^k$ with $k$ huge.

Enlarge $k$ enough so that

$$
g(k,y) = \log_2(f(2^k,y)) \sim \log_2(a) + (dy+e)(\log_2(b)+k)
$$

and now
$$g(k+1,0) - g(k,0) = e, \qquad g(k+1,1) - g(k,1) = d+e $$
gives you $d,e$.
$$g(k,y+1) - g(k,y) = d(\log_2(b) + k), \qquad g(k,0) = \log_2(a) + e(\log_2(b) + k)$$
gives you $b,a$. 
Now you can return to the original function and get $c$ through
$$f(0,0)=ac^e.$$